# Filter a doctrine ManyToMany Relationship by property of target

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

I have two entities `Item` and `Category` in a `ManyToMany` relationship.

When I run `$category->getItems()` on a `Category` I would like to filter the results by the property `visible` (boolean).

I remember that there was a `@ORM\Somewhat` Annotation, but I can't find it.

Category.php

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Item", mappedBy="categories")
* @ORM\OrderBy({"salable" = "DESC", "id" = "DESC"})
*/
private $items;
```

Item.php

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category", inversedBy="items")
*/
private $categories;
```

I want to get an `ArrayCollection` from the `$category->getItems()` function, only including those that are `visible`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no annotation for collection filtering.

To return only visible `Item` entities from a `Category` entity do the following:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;


public function getVisibleItems(): Collection
{
    $criteria = Criteria::create()
        ->andWhere(Criteria::expr()->eq('isVisible', true))
        ->orderBy(['createdAt' => 'DESC'])
    ;
    return $this->items->matching($criteria);
}
```

Comment: How to do for ManyToMany entities?